# C# (Xamarin) How to write JSON to array?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I have output in JSON.

```
{
  "id": null,
  "kkt": [],
  "CallNumber": null,
  "CallDuration": null,
  "CallDurationFormat": "00:00:00",
  "CallDateTick": 0,
  "CallDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "CallType": null,
  "CallDescription": "01/01/1970 12:00 a. m. -  | Duración: 00:00:00"
}
```

I want to write Call specification to kkt array like that:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "kkt": [
{

  "CallNumber": null,
  "CallDuration": null,
  "CallDurationFormat": "00:00:00",
  "CallDateTick": 0,
  "CallDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "CallType": null,
  "CallDescription": "01/01/1970 12:00 a. m. -  | Duración: 00:00:00"

}
],
}
```

For achieve this I created class Calls that I want serialize, but I dont know how to create List<> so that the specifications are in array.

Do someone have idea how I can write List<> or do something else to achieve that Call specs will be in kkt array?

Thank you for advices!

---

Classes:

CallLogModel: https://pastebin.com/nLeLszW0

CallLog: https://pastebin.com/fvS6s4SQ

ICallLog: https://pastebin.com/tz2uxDXw

Calls: https://pastebin.com/EWFgm2jx

LoadCallLog() method: https://pastebin.com/VATQnGG5

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  Relevant code should be posted in the body of the question, not as a link to an external site.

Comment: json2csharp.com will generate a C# model from a json dataset

Comment: As stated by other comments, it's a lot easier to answer your question when all the relevant code is available in the question.  From what I understand from your question, it looks like you are using c# properties and serializing them into json, but you want to serialize them into a json array.  To do this, you could use a Dictionary<string,object>() instead of c# properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change like below:

`Calls` model:

```
public class Calls 
{

    public string id;
    public List<CallLogModel> kkt;
}
```

`ICallLog` interface:

```
public interface ICallLog
{
    List<CallLogModel> GetCallLogs();
}
```

then in your `LoadCallLog()` method you need to add the value that you queried into the `Calls` model like:

```
var Logg = DependencyService.Get<ICallLog>().GetCallLogs();

if (!(Preferences.ContainsKey("GUID")))
   {
       Preferences.Set("GUID", App.newUser1);
   }
 var a = Preferences.Get("GUID", "hovno"); //if this is the id of Calls model
 Calls calls = new Calls();
 calls.id = a;
 calls.kkt = Logg;
 var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(calls);
```